# Question about Switching Between Random Variables

Tags: probability

Find the density function of $Y = aX$, where $a > 0$, in terms of the density function of $X$.
Show that the continuous random variables $X$ and $-X$ 
have the same distribution function if and only if $f_X(x) = f_X(-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

I got the first part already.  $$F_Y(y) = \mathbb P(Y = aX \le y) = \mathbb P(X \le y/a) = F_X(y/a)$$
Hence, $$f_Y(y) = {1 \over a} f_X(y/a)$$
But for the second part, I cannot get the subscripts to match. 
This is what I mean ...  $( \rightarrow)$ Let $Y = -X$.
$$F_Y(y) = \mathbb P(Y = -X \le y) = \mathbb P(X \gt -y) = 1 - F_X(x)$$
$$f_Y(y) = -f_X(x) * {{dx} \over {dy}} = f_X(x)$$
So $f_{-X}(-x) = f_X(x)$, which is different from what the text claimed. 
I always have troubles understanding the subscripts in $F_Y$ or $f_X$. 
A lot of times I have difficulty switching from one random variable to another. 
So, in this example, the text is claiming that
$$\mathbb P(X(\omega) \le -x) = \mathbb P(X(\omega) \le x)$$
That makes me think that $f_X = 0$ between $-x$ and $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y = -X$, $f_{-X}(-x) = f_X(x)$ is the same as $f_Y(t) = f_X(-t)$ where $t = -x$.  Saying $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution says that $f_Y(t) = f_X(t)$.
So this is exactly the same.

And how could you possibly argue with
$ {\mathbb P}(X(\omega)\le -x) =  {\mathbb P}(X(\omega)\le -x)$?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.

Comment: The new version is clearly wrong.  Perhaps you mean
${\mathbb P}(X(\omega) \le -x) = {\mathbb P}(X(\omega) \ge x)$.

Comment: Hello Professor, I see my misinterpretation now.  Thanks for setting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $F_{-X}(y)=P_X(X\geq -y)=1-P_X(X< -y)$. Now apply $\frac{d}{dy}$ to both sides, arriving at

$$f_{-X}(y)=-\frac{d}{dy}\int_{-\infty}^{-y}f_{X}(x)dx;$$

taking care of the extra minus sign on the r.h.s. you arrive at $f_{-X}(y)=f_{X}(-y)$, and you can conclude the proof.

Answer (score 0):

If $a < 0$, your calculation
$$F_Y(y) = \mathbb P(Y = aX \le y) = \mathbb P(X \le y/a) = F_X(y/a)$$
for $a > 0$ changes to
$$F_Y(y) = \mathbb P(Y = aX \le y) = \mathbb P(X \ge y/a) = 1- F_X(y/a)$$
since $1-F_X(x) = P\{X > x\}$ equals $P\{X \geq x\}$ for continuous random variables. Thus,
we get $$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}-{1 \over a} f_X(y/a), & a < 0,\\
{1 \over a} f_X(y/a), & a > 0,\end{cases} ~~ = \frac{1}{|a|}f_X\left(\frac{y}{a}\right), ~ a \neq 0$$
which directly gives that $f_{-X}(y) = f_X(-y)$ for all $y$. Hence, $-X$ and $X$
have the same distribution, viz. $f_{-X}(y) = f_X(y) ~\forall y \in \mathbb R$ iff
$f_{X}(-y) = f_X(y) ~\forall y \in \mathbb R$.